# Displaying current position using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, position

How can I display my current position in the QGIS canvas, similar to the "blue point" in google mapsa?

I need this to navigate to defined points and I do not want to change the program all the time.

Comment: You don't. Make an My Maps account at Google, import your points. Then use My Maps app that works with Google Maps. Then you just click on your points and it will navigate. Qgis aren't geocentric as many mobile apps.

Comment: @Salliva2000 thank you and sorry for the late response. I sickened and wasn't inn the office for this time. This means for me, that if I need to edit attributes while I am at this point, I need both: mymaps to navigate and QGIS (on a laptop for instance) to edit (e.g. to mark and comment these points).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the location of your IP address with this python code:

`import requests
import json
send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
r = requests.get(send_url)
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
map_pos = QgsPoint(lon, lat)
rect = QgsRectangle(map_pos, map_pos)
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(rect)
canvas.refresh()`

This will find your estimated location, based on your IP address, and center the map on that location.